# React-Navigation 5 - Passing values between screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I was used to getParam in Navigation 4 to pass values between screens, now I'm a bit lost in version 5. I made an Expo Snack to better understand the problem I'm having: https://snack.expo.io/@mobshed/navigation-5---passing-values

In case the snack is not clear, I would like to pass the topic's value from Screen1 to Screen2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is because route param in not embedded in curly braces.
I tried using this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  AsyncStorage,
  Dimensions,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
  Alert,
  RefreshControl,
  Animated,
  Easing,
  Image,
  Button
} from "react-native";
import MyScreen1 from "./App.js";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MyScreen2({route}) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      <Text>itemId: {route.params?.topic ?? "defaultValue"}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default MyScreen2;
```

and it worked

Comment: Thanks a lot, Saurav!

Answer (score 1):

The @Saurav answer is correct. Still, I would like to add to it. I may suggest rewriting *MyScreen2* as:

```
export default MyScreen2 = ({route}) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      <Text>itemId: {route.params?.topic ?? "defaultValue"}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

What happens here:

1. a "map" of *{navigation:{}, route:{…}}* gets passed to MyScreen2 as a parameter;
2. *{route}* is a syntax for destructuring the map from [1];
3. Then you can access *topic* using the expression from the question.

So if you need to add some navigation logic onto *MyScreen2* in the future, you may destructure *navigation* as well.